# How to detect how many Rest items are available

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have following issue:

I need to detect how many objects are available in remote service.

For example:

```
url="https://myapi/";
getPerson(personsId){
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(`${this.url}${personsId}`,{headers:this.headers});
  }
  getAllPersons(){
    let numberOfPersons // in this variable I want to store how many items are available.
    const response = [...Array(numberOfPersons).keys()].map(i => this.getPerson(i+1));
    return forkJoin(response).pipe(map(value=> value),share());
  }
}
```

Where numberOfPersons is the number of items.

Comment: Means you want total length of records which are getting from `getPerson()` http.get request.

Comment: yes exactly that

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
getPersonCountForId(personId): Observable<number> {
  return this.getPerson(personId).pipe( 
    map(persons => persons.length),
  );
}
```

Comment: I need to hold last index of personId available. is it this?

Comment: For last index you likely need the decrement of length

Comment: so how to do it?